# onclick to add another script is not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a page where JavaScript will do something like:

When i click a link named "update" it will hide the div named "hide" run another script that is linked by JavaScript.

But when i click "Update" it just hide the div but doesn't run the script on mobile or Firefox. It's working on Google Chrome.

```js
var myLink = document.getElementById('mylink');

myLink.onclick = function () {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "js/wa_lock.js.";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
    return false;
}

$("#mylink").click(function () {
    $("#hide").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hide">
    <h1 class="big">Update Required!</h1>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <img src="images/logo.png" class="logo" />

        <p class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>

        <p class="txt">Nullam sit amet mauris pellentesque, fermentum lacus vitae, ultrices ligula. Praesent odio dui, volutpat id faucibus non, facilisis eget lacus.</p>

        <img src="images/msg.png" class="logo" />

        <p class="now">facilisis eget lacus <span id="timer"></span> Vivamus hendrerit velit purus</p>

        <div class="bottom">
            <p class="rules">1.Curabitur quis dolor ligula. Nullam erat neque, ornare nec massa quis, blandit dignissim tortor. Sed velit lacus, tempus quis lorem sed, efficitur mattis justo.</p>
            <p class="rules">2. Donec mattis, nibh eu porttitor lobortis, erat neque placerat orci, ac egestas velit arcu eu augue. Morbi viverra sapien in ultricies pulvinar.</p>
            <a href="#" id="mylink">Update</a>                    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: script.src = "js/wa_lock.js."; is your address is correct?

Comment: also it will be great if you copy js/wa_lock.js here

Comment: It would probably be better to include `wa_lock.js` in the page directly, but encapsulate the logic in it within a function which you can call when the click event happens.

Answer (score 1):

You are hiding `#hide` in the main script. Here:

```
script.src = "js/wa_lock.js.";
```

it seems that you unnecessarily have a point at the end of the path. Maybe this would be better:

```
script.src = "js/wa_lock.js";
```

Also, it is not clear what wa-lock.js is doing. Maybe it is loading later than the moment you hide, so you could consider adding the hiding part to the wa_lock.js file. Finally, you should check your console to see whether there are any js errors and the networks tab to check whether the script was loaded correctly.

Comment: wa_lock.js file will be load while click update link and the other content will hide at the same time. I have also tried by adding the hiding part into the wa_lock.js file but still it doesn't work. also i want to say that this functions are running perfectly on Google Chrome but not working on other browsers